# Tableau combine Max and Count with filters

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau Desktop 2018.1.

I am building a dashboard that shows the top 1 user feedback item for each of 4 categories.

My current dashboard version calculates the top user feedback item for the whole dataset and then displays how often that feedback item occurs for each filter that I apply.

I need it to (re-)calculate the max Count for each set of filters I apply in the dashboard instead.

I want to be able to filter the data by 4 location fields and by week / month quarter year.

I am applying these 3 calculated fields.

1) IF [Item]="Issues" THEN {FIXED [Reason Code], [Category]:Count([Item])} END
2) IF [Item]="Issues" THEN {FIXED [Category]:Max([Reason Count])} END
3) IF {FIXED [Category]:MAX([Reason Count])}={FIXED [Reason Code],[Category]:Count([Job])} THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END

How do I make that when I filter it re-calculates the 3 calculated fields.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your filters to Context should give you your desired re-calculation. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_context.htm

Answer (score 0):

Let me repeat the question to make sure I interpreted it correctly. You would like to find the most common feedback, independently, across four categories.

If that's what you are after I'll use the example of finding the most popular sub-category of items across three categories.

```
Side note: Put your Item field on the filters shelf, set it to "Issues" and add it to context. I'll use State in my example.
```

[image]

I'll then add the categories to the column shelf, sub-categories to the rows and display the count of sub-categories within each category.

[image]

We then need to create our calculation showing of which are the top sub-categories within each category.

[image]

I'll place this calculation on the color shelf for now.

[image]

We want this table calculation to run across the sub-categories and partition by the categories. Therefore, you'll want these settings.

[image]

With those settings, you'll see something like this...

[image]

To see which sub-categories we should expect to see when the filter is applied let's add sub-categories to the text shelf.

[image]

Now we know we should expect to see furnishing, binders, and phones sub-categories respectively. Let's now move our calculation to the filter shelf and select True.

[image]

The last step is to simply remove the sub-category dimension from the rows self.

[image]

Good luck! It's a complex task to get right.